# Laravel Custom Exceptions Configuration

Tags: php, error-handling, exception, laravel-5.3

I have been trying to implement some custom Exceptions in Laravel 5.3 with no luck.

I have created an AppException which extends the Exception class. The idea of this is that I would like to attach a user to my exceptions so I know who tripped it and can log it.

So I set up my custom exception like this:

```
class AppException extends Exception{

    protected $userId;

    public function __construct($message = '', $userId=0)
    {
        parent::__construct($message);
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }
}
```

Now what I would like is to use try catch's in my controller functions and then catch an exception and then rethrow the app exception so I can attach the user. Like this:

```
try{
    << code here >>
}
catch(Exception $e){
    throw new AppException($e->getMessage, $request->user()->id);
}
```

What I am finding is that I am unable to get a good trace stack because the line I am logging from my exception is the line from the rethrow in the catch, not from the actual exception.

What would be the right way to set this up? I am trying to do this in a way where I can utilize the built in Handler.php file that comes with Laravel instead of having to put in log code in every try catch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`Exception`](http://php.net/manual/it/class.exception.php) class has a `previous` argument that you can use to retrieve all the previous Exception.

```
class AppException extends Exception
{
    private $userId;

    public function __construct($userId, $message = '', $code = 0, Exception $previous = null)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;

        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    public static function fromUserId($userId, Exception $previous = null)
    {
        return new static($userId, sprintf('Exception thrown from `%s` userid', $userId), 0, $previous);
    }

    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }
}
```

Or just simply

```
class AppException extends Exception
{
    public static function fromUserId($userId, Exception $previous = null)
    {
        return new static(sprintf('Exception thrown from `%s` userid', $userId), 0, $previous);
    }
}
```

After you catch `AppException` you can iterate all the exception like this:

```
do {
    printf("%s:%d %s (%d) [%s]\n", $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), get_class($e));
} while($e = $e->getPrevious());
```

Example:

```
try {
    try{
        throw new RuntimeException('Something bad happened.');
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        throw AppException::fromUserId(123, $e);
    }
} catch(AppException $e) {
    do {
        printf("%s:%d %s (%d) [%s]\n", $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), get_class($e));
    } while($e = $e->getPrevious());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching the actual exception to the thrown exception, for example like this:

```
class AppException extends \Exception
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @param \Exception $exception
     * @param int        $userId
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public static function fromExceptionAndUserId(\Exception $exception, $userId)
    {
        $instance = new self(
            $exception->getMessage(),
            0,
            $exception
        );

        $instance->userId = $userId;

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * @return null|int
     */
    public function userId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    throw AppException::fromExceptionAndUserId(
        $exception, 
        $request->user()->id
    );
}
```

The idea is to not only use the actual exception message, but to also attach the actual exception as `$previous` exception.

Using a named constructor gives you the advantage that you can control how the exception message of `AppException` is constructed (while also attaching the user identifier), as well as still being able to use the original `AppException` constructor. It gives you the freedom to add more named constructors for different use cases, too.

For reference, see

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php
- http://verraes.net/2014/06/named-constructors-in-php/